# pragma solidity - compilation error in jpmorganchase cakeshop

Tags: sdk, ethereum, solidity, truffle, quorum

I am running a simple code from SimpleStorage example and just added few lines on top of it which I was using for my other contracts. The contract compiles fine from truffle. But on the Cakeshop Integrated IDE it shows compilation error.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
contract SimpleStorage {

    uint public storedData; 

    event Change(string message, uint newVal);

    function SimpleStorage(uint initVal) {
        Change("initialized", initVal);
        storedData = initVal;
    }

    function set(uint x) {
        Change("set", x);
        storedData = x;
    }

    function get() constant returns (uint retVal) {
        return storedData;
    }

}
```

It should compile on the cakeshop web UI as it compiles on local machine

Answer (score 1):

Utilizing Remix, it seems the following could be potential issues with your contract:

1. You are using the Contract name for the constructor. You should use the `constructor` keyword instead.
2. All of your functions are missing visibility modifiers. Consider adding the `public` modifier to each function including the constructor.
3. Events should be invoked using the `emit` keyword. Example: `emit Change("set", x);`